# multiple if, else statment and getting error.

Tags: r

I have a matrix called A,
I want to retrieve it's element given coordinate. I did coordinate transformation.
here is my piece of code to do this task, but I don't know, why I get error. could somebody help me ? it's get the coordinate (i, j) from user and retrieve matrix element at coordinate. 
the error is :

> unexpected end of input

```
    p<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Pleae enter 1 to get coordinate of number,and 2 to get the number > "));

    if(p==1){
    # get the number, given coordniate 
     i<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Pleae enter i cordinate > "));
     j<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Pleae enter j cordinate > "));
    Getvalue<- function(i,j){
        if (i>=0) A[2+i,2+j]
        else      A[2+i,2-j]

        Getvalue
    }else if (p==2){
   # do this 
}
```

Comment: Count your brackets - I think you're missing a closing `}`

Comment: I did it, doesn't work again

Comment: The `else` on it's own line probably does not work...

Comment: the first block doesn't work also (without else if ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
foo <- function(){
p<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Please enter 1 to get coordinate of number, and 2 to get the number > "))

if(p==1){
  # get the number, given coordniate 
  i<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Please enter i cordinate > "))
  j<- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Please enter j cordinate > "))
  Getvalue <- function(i,j){
    if (i>=0) {
      return(A[2+i,2+j])
    } else{
      return(A[2+i,2-j])
    }      
  }
  Getvalue(i, j)
} else  if (p==2){
  print("Do this")
  }

}

###Example:
> # a dummy matrix 
> set.seed(1)
> A <- matrix(sample(100, 100, TRUE), 10)
> # If p=1, i=2, j=2, then 19 should be returned.

> foo() # executing `foo()` to values from the terminal 
Please enter 1 to get coordinate of number, and 2 to get the number > 1
Please enter i cordinate > 2
Please enter j cordinate > 2
[1] 19
> foo()
Please enter 1 to get coordinate of number, and 2 to get the number > 2
[1] "Do this"
```

Read the documentation of [`readline`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readline.html) and try to understand the example shown inthere.